# VBA - select user inputted years from a list of dates

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a worksheet with dates listed in separate rows in ascending order as follows:

```
10/03/1995
29/04/1995
25/09/1995
11/07/1997
04/10/1997
02/04/1998
13/07/1998
23/08/1998
11/10/1998
05/06/1999
07/06/1999
10/06/1999
06/05/2000
03/07/2000
15/05/2001
09/07/2001
03/08/2002
11/08/2002
11/09/2002
12/10/2002
16/11/2002
15/12/2002
22/01/2003
17/02/2003
14/03/2003
27/04/2003
28/05/2003
14/07/2003
15/08/2003
10/11/2003
05/12/2003
```

I intend on implementing an input box where the user can enter a start year and an end year. If the user inputs a year range such as 1995 - 2000, how can I only select all the dates from 1995-2000 without having to modify the data (for example using delimiter "/") ?

Comment: `RIGHT()` is your friend.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Right() as Tripp pointed out.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i as long
Dim j as long
Dim r as Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the first column
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        if right(ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value, 4) >= lowYear and right(ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value, 4) <= highYear then

            if i = 0 then
                i = lRow
                j = lROw
            else
                j = lRow
            end if

        End if

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    Dim str As String
    str = "A" & i & ":A" & j
    Set r = Range(str)
    r.Select
```

Comment: This is great! I should  have been more specific but how would i assign those values to a range and select only those values?

Comment: What are you going to do with those values. Why do you want to select them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with an `AutoFilter` so that you don't have to loop thru all your rows.

It filters the dates within your range, selects them, then removes the filter.

```
intYearStart = 1995
intYearEnd   = 2000
intLastRow   = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

With Range("A1:A" & intLastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=1/1/" & intYearStart, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=12/31/" & intYearEnd
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    .AutoFilter
End With
```